# Assign value to current instance of Carbon

Tags: php, php-carbon

(I guess this would be simple, but can't google it (maybe because I can't phrase it well enough)

How do I modify the value of an instance of `Carbon` and set **its value** to another instance of `Carbon`? So for example, I have got two `Carbon` instances `$start` and `$end`. I want `$start`'s value to become equal to `$end`, but keeping it to point to the original instance. I can't do:

```
$start = $end;
```

because I'll lose reference to the original instance. Similarly, built-in methods like `parse()` also create a new instance, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Carbon's documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-setters), you can use the `setDateTimeFrom` method:

```
$start->setDateTimeFrom($end);
```

Comment: Ah, there you go. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Try

$start->setTimestamp($end->timestamp);

Comment: This seems equally good now that I just found that Carbon actually inherits from built-in DateTime.